# Is there a function to give the name of repo/object/table/project by RID (Ressource Identifier)

Tags: palantir-foundry, foundry-code-repositories, palantir-foundry-api

using an API that give me the list of projects by RID, i want to know if it's possible to know  the name of each project.
for example this rid 'ri.compass.main.folder.*****' related to 'Mehdi' folder name
is there a method to do that in code repository ?

I don't found an API to do that !

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried hitting with a GET
`yourstack.com/compass/api/ui/resources/ri.compass.main.folder.9d079c06-d924-43f7-a973-a643e8259d57/location`?

You'll get the whole file structure in the reply and can get the names from there.

Comment: except the authorization using the token, they are another pram or json content ?, the reponse using this get is empty

Comment: You should have the docs for the API on your stack, should have more details there